# Which form (singular vs plural) should I use for a verb governed by a collective noun?

Tags: american-english, subject-verb-agreement, grammatical-number, collective-nouns

For context, let me clarify.  When giving ownership to a person, I
can use the *’s* form of that person’s name.

1. This is *Robert’s* car.

When attributing ownership to two people or more, I can still add
a final *’s* after their two (or more) **first** names together as a unit:

2. Those are **Lucia and John’s** cars, respectively.

Yet if I want to express ownership by people from the same family,
the *’s* clitic now requires *the* plus their **last** name:

3. This is **the Souza’s** house.

So it’s safe to say that *the* followoed a family name always refers to
collective ownership by several people.

With that said, what if I want to know the quantity of objects owned
by a given family?  Do I use a singular verb because it’s one single
family taken as a whole, or do I use a plural verb because it’s
multiple individuals?

So should I go with a plural verb like this:

4. How many houses **do** the Souza have?

or with a singular verb like this:

5. How many houses **does** the Souza have?

I’ve got a feeling I should go with plural *do* because I’m referring
to more than one person (that is, to all the Souza family members),
but I’d like my hunch confirmed or disputed so that I can be certain
I’m doing this correctly.

Comment: How many houses do the Souza**s** have? (plural s), this is the Souza**s'** house (plural possessive of word ending in s)

Comment: You appear to have copied into English a Portuguese way of using the
singular family name as a plural in a non-English way. In PT, the *Ferreira
Gomes* family are *os Ferreira Gomes* with only a plural "the" yet plural
concord for the verb: *“os Ferreira Gomes são”* not *“os ✴Ferreiras ✴Gomeses
são”*. EG: [“Nesse caso, os índios substimaram os Ferreira, pensando que
estes fugiriam após o aviso inicial de
flechadas.”](http://www.jornaldopovorn.com.br/2.1564/a-morte-de-antonio-ferreira-de-lima-6-1.2221151) In English, we pluralize the surname, saying that *the Ferreira**s** are* instead.

Answer (score 7):

First, the second paragraph in your question is incorrect.

If you're talking about individual ownership, the apostrophe goes after *each* person's name:

> Those are **Lucia's** and **John's** cars, respectively.

If they *both* own the *same* car, then you put the apostrophe only after the last person's name:

> That is **Lucia and John's** car.

You can't mix up the two things.

---

As for the main point of the question, you can use either of the following:

- How many houses **do** the ***Suozas*** have?
- How many houses **does** the ***Souza family*** have?

Note the plurality in the first version, but without the use of an apostrophe.

Comment: But if they both own more than one car, then "Lucia and John's cars" would be correct, right?

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain myself clearly.
On the second paragraph, by "Those are Lucia and John's cars, respectively", I meant that each one has a different car, that's why car is in the plural and then I added, respectively because I'm mentioning one car after the other, while still referring to its owner, for each.
But thank you for the hint, by putting the last name in the plural, I guess it makes more evident and therefore less likely to have that doubt I did before.

Comment: @AIQ No. It would still be *Lucia's and John's cars*, it would simply be ambiguous how many cars *each* of them has. If they jointly own more than a single car, then it *would* be *Lucia and John's* ***cars***.

Comment: @RodolfoFerreira Yes, exactly. I understood what you were saying. Lucia has a car, so it's *Lucia's car* (with an apostrophe), and John has a car, so it's *John's car* with an apostrophe. Put them together, and it's **Lucia's** *and* **John's** ***cars***.

Comment: I see. I got it now. Well, then I guess this sentence is incorrect: "Lucia's and John's CAR"; That's because I'm using 's for each owner, so there has to be TWO or more owned objects (one car for each owner) in the context. Is that it? :S

Comment: @RodolfoFerreira Quite so. They can't, separately, own a single car. Not unless there is some strange logic game in place where, for example, one has complete ownership of the left half of the car and the other has complete ownership of the right half of the car … (But if that were the case, I'm sure it would be explained differently.)

Comment: Heh, marriage does that to you. Only in this case, you replace the car with a house and there ya go. Final question, this just came in: What if John has one car and Lucia's got more than one? I guess the difference in number has to be indicated after the owner: "John's car and Lucia's cars" - but that's redundant. How to fix that? I mean, if you try and work with Demonstratives, it could look less ugly: "This is John's car and those are Lucia's cars", but because we're talking the SAME OBJECT, it could be: "This is John's car and those are Lucia's" ? It still sounds weird tho.

Comment: @RodolfoFerreira Right. You can still say *John's and Lucia's cars*, but it's ambiguous how many cars each of them actually has. (Normally, we would assume one each, but that doesn't have to be the case.) You have to phrase it differently if you want to be specific, and all of your variations are possible. It just comes down to which sounds best—or, possibly, which sounds the least bad, if you don't like any of them. An alternative (which you might think sounds just as bad) is *Those are Lucia's two cars and John's single car.*

Comment: XD We're killing it here!

Answer (score 6):

If you want to talk about "the people called 'Souza'", they are "The Souzas" (plural), and so if you must you can say "the Souzas' house" (again plural).

As a question,  "How many houses do the Souzas have".  You use "do" because "the Souzas" is plural.

Its possible to use "Souza" attributively and say "How many houses does the Souza family have?"  This time it is the singular "family" so we use "does".

I feel there is a bit of translationese in this structure.  Houses are not usually owned by a family. Normally a couple will own the house, and their children live in the house without having any ownership of it.  It is often not public what the legal ownership of a house is. It would be more natural to say "How many houses does Rodolfo own?" rather than speak of "the Ferreiras".

Comment: Yeah but doesn't THE already indicate *more than one person*?
I mean, do I always *have to* type the surname in plural?
As far as I know, THE doesn't come before a first name - that's because for INDIVIDUAL ownership, THE isn't used. Am I correct?

Comment: @RodolfoFerreira It's possible to use the plural with first names too. For example, *John Smith and John Doe went for a walk. The Johns were known for walking together.* If multiple people share the same name (first or last) you can use the plural to describe them collectively.

Comment: The word "the" doesn't indicate more than one person; you need to use the plural of the surname.  You are treating the name as a common noun if you use "the", and since it is always used to refer to more than one person in this context, you must use the plural. It is also possible to use the name attributively "The Souza family" and this is probalby better in most cases.

Comment: @RodolfoFerreira How many cars does **the** Pope have?  "The" just indicates that there is some form of title at play, it does not indicated whether it is for an individual or a group.

Comment: I don't think it's translationese at all, though the first thing I thought of was adult children, for example "How many houses do the Clintons own?" including parents Bill and Hillary plus their daughter Chelsea.

Comment: Also, aside from some specific regional exceptions, English has plural agreement for nouns and verbs (though not adjectives). So yes, you generally need to indicate plurals more than once in a sentence. So even if "the" indicated plural (which it doesn't, same as it doesn't indicate gender), you'd still pluralize the noun. For example, numbers greater than one indicate plural, but you still pluralize the noun.

Comment: Another example might help:

"This is the guest's car." = A car that belongs to one guest
"This is the guests' car." = A car that belongs to multiple guests

The sentences are the same except for the singular/plural possessive.